# How to fix error "Failed to compile : ./node_modules/@itwin/object-storage- azure/lib/frontend/wrappers/FrontendBlockBlobClientWrapper.js 17:59

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a react-typescript app along with Bentley. And I have installed all the dependencies.

But when I start the application it says:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (17:59)
The file was processed with these loaders:
* ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     }
|     async uploadInMultipleParts(data, options) {
>         const { metadata, partSize, queueSize } = options ?? {};
|         const dataBuffer = await (0, internal_1.streamToBufferFrontend)(data);
|         await this._client.uploadData(dataBuffer, {
```

I tried reinstalling dependencies several times but still didn't work.

Comment: there's an unexpected token on line 17, position 59 of some file you possibly haven't indicated